# Angular typescript gives wrong boolean result - Ionic

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I am building a random generator where the user needs to enter maximum and minimum number to generate random between that number. So the application will returns error on two condition:

1. If either numbers are negative value
2. If maximum number is less than minimum number

this is my code showing the method generate number:

```
generateRandomNumber(max, min) {
console.log(max<min);
  if(max > min && min > 0){
    this.number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + parseInt(min);
    this.err_compare = false;
    this.err_negative = false;
  }
  else if(max < 0 || min < 0){
    this.err_negative = true;
  }
  else if(max < min){
    this.err_compare = true;
  }

}
```

> When I input max = 10 and min = 1, it returns **false**. But when I change min =2, the log returns **true**.

[Click Here to see the log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDRnz.png)

Can someone explain why this happens?

**UPDATE**

As a follow up to Mr @Setu, I tested myself by plugging in the number directly into the function and return the correct result so I assume something went wrong in the input. Here's the markup:

```
 <form #generator="ngForm">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label for="max" floating>Maximum</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="max" name="max" required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label for="min" floating>Minimum</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="min" name="min" required></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
  <br>
  <button default ion-button block [disabled]="!generator.valid" (click)="generateRandomNumber(max,min)">Generate</button>
 </form>
```

From what I see, it is detecting as if I am about to key in

```
20,21,22...
```

" when I only what to key in

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your function but it returns the correct answer. Check my console log below

[image]